# how to display label in top of checkout page

Tags: magento2

i am using magento 2.3.4 and now integrated with amasty once step checkout unfortunatly its not working.Magento once step checkout Shipping Address alignment not working

Comment: anyone help me.checkout label display in top of the text box

Comment: Please ask extension vendor it will give you better idea.

Comment: in Magento 2 one CSS file path not found how to add custom google fonts in magento 2

Comment: You must get help from the extension developer.